# Gradle build on Jenkins failed

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Due to some internal Gradle issues the build on Jenkins is failing.
It seems quiet known issue to Gradle.

Links:

- [Issue 227592:   NPE in NDK support in 2.3 canary1](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227592)
- [Issue 218844:   NullPointerException when configuring gradle build containing CMake external native build](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218844)

My project does not use Android NDK.

- Gradle wrapper version: **2.14.1**
- Android Gradle plugin version: **2.2.3**
- Build tools: **23.0.3**

Here is a **stacktrace**:

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':TestLauncher'.
01:02:01    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:540)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:93)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:121)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:31)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
01:02:01 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.DefaultNdkInfo.findTargetPlatformVersionOrLower(DefaultNdkInfo.java:167)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.DefaultNdkInfo.findLatestPlatformVersion(DefaultNdkInfo.java:89)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getPlatformVersion(NdkHandler.java:131)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.supports64Bits(NdkHandler.java:234)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getSupportedAbis(NdkHandler.java:297)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.StripDebugSymbolTransform.<init>(StripDebugSymbolTransform.java:86)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createStripNativeLibraryTask(TaskManager.java:1342)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager.createTasksForVariantData(ApplicationTaskManager.java:289)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createTasksForVariantData(VariantManager.java:485)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$3.call(VariantManager.java:293)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$3.call(VariantManager.java:290)
01:02:01    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
01:02:01    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.java:44)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:286)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$11.call(BasePlugin.java:688)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$11.call(BasePlugin.java:685)
01:02:01    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
01:02:01    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:683)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:608)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:605)
01:02:01    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
01:02:01    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
01:02:01    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$1(BasePlugin.java:603)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
01:02:01    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
01:02:01    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
01:02:01    ... 44 more
01:02:01 
01:02:01 
01:02:01 BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem, it was building fine until some component updated on the build server and now it does not compile. Did you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the problem in building the initial project from React-Native. It seems caused by different Gradle version used in the project.

Change the gradle version used in the project. In /android/build.gradle

Original:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`

Modified:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'`

Also change the source of Gradle in /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Original:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`

Modified:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

Hope this can solve the problem.